# Sum of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series

My book writes the following:

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)\pi i}e^{t(\frac{2n-1}{a})\pi i}=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)}\sin(\frac{2n-1}{a}\cdot\pi t)$

where $t$ and $a\ne0$ are real constants.
I think the author is missing the value for $n=0$, namely: $\sin(t\pi/a)$
So the right sum should be:$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)\pi i}e^{t(\frac{2n-1}{a})\pi i}=\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\frac{t\pi}{a}) +\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)}\sin(\frac{2n-1}{a}\cdot\pi t)$$

Am I right?

Comment: I don't have to calculate the sum, tell me if the author is making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

It is right that the term for $n=0$ must be included, but this term is $\frac{-1}{i\pi}e^{\frac{-i \pi}{a}}$.